# Why are those leafs drying?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, bonsai

[image: cheatnut]

[image: ceviz]

[image: pine]

Why are they drying and how can I save them. They are in front of yhe window facing north. There is an apartment across very close. So not too much sunlight but enough I guess. I am in İstanbul.

I don't water the leafs and water them bidaily.

Answer (score 1):

Do the roots still have enough room? If not, repot in a bigger container. If they do still seem to have enough roots, maybe giving them some magnesium sulfate (epsom salt) in a watering could help; a teaspoon for every 3-5 liters of water (every watering until it subsides, unless it gets worse, since then it would not be the right solution) would be a good dose.

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be multiple issues.  Still take Barry's advice, I just see two more possible problems.  One look for webbing under the leaves and on the conifer.  It looks like they might have spider mite.  If you do have the webbing the first thing to do is wash off the leaves and needles using your bathroom shower.   The first picture looks like the leaves are covered in a white film.  But, I can't really tell.  If it is, it's powdery mildew.   The conifer is best outdoor, it needs 2-3 months of cool weather, preferably cold weather to kill off spider mite.   The other plants I can not identify from the pictures. It maybe a plant that drops it's leaves in fall.  A deciduous plant.  They definitely needs some cool weather months.  They will grow new healthy leaves in spring.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have these plants but symptoms seems to be same and matching with issue with my dieffenbachia, problem turned out to be with spider mites, they were having time of their life while killing my plant, Leaves were curling with brown tips and white spots.

This is what i did , every morning i spray the leaves with Cold water and now they are gone , and plant is back to its good health

now these spider mites are very very tiny like nano tiny when you might have opened the windows they came flying in with the wind